# independent random variables L1

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $X, Y$ be two independent, integrable random variables. Starting just from $||XY||_1=||X||_1||Y||_1$, is it possible to deduce that $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$?

I'm interested in a measure theoretic point of view.

My thoughts: Since $X, Y$ are integrable, so are $|X|, |Y|$ and from $||XY||_1=||X||_1||Y||_1$, $|XY|$ is also integrable. So we have $\mathbb{E}(|XY|)=\mathbb{E}(|X|)\mathbb{E}(|Y|)$. But how does this imply $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$?

Comment: What does 'just from...' mean? are you asking if independence is not needed?

Comment: I mean knowing that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, integrable, we can prove directly using the joint density formula that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. I'm interested $||XY||_1=||X||_1 ||Y||_1$ can imply that directly, without using joint density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=Y$ and $X,Y$ take values $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each then $\|XY\|_1=1=\|X\|_1\|Y\|_1$ but $EXY \neq EX EY$. So deducing $EXY = EX EY$ just from $\|XY\|_1=1=\|X\|_1\|Y\|_1$ (without using independence)  is not possible.

Comment: I'm assuming that $X, Y$ are independent. What I am asking is that if $||XY||_1=||X||_1 ||Y||_1$ can be used to prove $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: Of course my random variables are integrable.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant independent.

Comment: If you are using independence you can follow the usual proof. The equation $\|XY\|_1=\|X\|_1\|Y\|_1$ is not useful.